# How to Increment Variables dynamically

Tags: bash, variable

How to increment variables dynamically.
I have written below script but it is giving an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
X='101 Hari BAN'
for i in "${X[@]}"
    do
            "V"$j=`echo $i|cut -d' ' -f$j`              
            echo "V"$j
            j=`expr $j + 1`
    done
```

Output should be,

```
V1=101
V2=Hari
V3=BAN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are using `bash` and you want to iterate over *separate things*, then use an array:

```
X=( 101 Hari BAN "many words" "a * in the sky" )
```

This allows you to handle string that contain whitespaces and filename globbing patterns correctly by appropriately quoting those strings.

Then loop over the array:

```
X=( 101 Hari BAN "many words" "a * in the sky" )

for item in "${X[@]}"; do

done
```

Then, it's a matter of outputting the result.  For this we use a counter and `printf`:

```
X=( 101 Hari BAN "many words" "a * in the sky" )

n=0
for item in "${X[@]}"; do
    printf 'V%d=%s\n' "$(( ++n ))" "$item"
done
```

The `printf` format string `V%d=%s\n` means "The character `V` followed by an integer, then a `=` and some string. End with newline".  The integer and string is taken from the remaining arguments to `printf`.  The variable `n` is incremented before being used by the `printf`.

Add the correct `#!`-line pointing to your `bash` interpreter and you're done.

The output would be

```
V1=101
V2=Hari
V3=BAN
V4=many words
V5=a * in the sky
```

---

According to comments below, you were expecting `V1`, `V2` to be variables, but they obviously are just text in the output.

Again, what I think you need here is not separate variables but an array.

In fact, the array that we already have, `X` already contains the necessary data, so we could just rename it.

```
#!/bin/bash

V=( 101 Hari BAN )

for i in "${!V[@]}"; do
    printf 'V[%s] = %s\n' "$i" "${V[i]}"
done
```

That is, you simply use `"${V[0]}"`, `"${V[1]}"`, etc. to access the elements of the array `V`.

Comment: Thank you. It is working. But I'm unable to use V1,V2,V3,V4,V5 variables. So can you please help me.

Comment: @Harisha You said nothing in the question about these being variables. You said you wanted a particular output...  I'll make an edit, hold on.

Comment: @Harisha Hi. I don't give out personal information like that to people on this site (and you shouldn't either). If you have further questions, you should ask a new question on the site. If needed, you can provide a link to this question in the new question as a reference and then say what the new issue is.

Comment: It's difficult to read unformatted code. You should ask a new question, as I suggested, not add further questions in comments.